# How to pull a list of all visitor_ids that have visited at least twice in January 2020, but did not transact (in ANY of their January visits)

Tags: sql, window-functions

Tables:

1. Sessions

   - session_ts
   - visitor_id
   - vertical
   - session_id
2. Transactions

   - session_ts
   - session_id
   - rev_bucket
   - revenue

Currently have the following query (using SQLite):

```
SELECT
   visitor_id,
   session_id,
   running_total
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      s.visitor_id,
      s.session_id,
      t.revenue,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.visitor_id ORDER BY t.session_ts) as row_num,
      SUM(revenue) OVER(PARTITION BY s.visitor_id) as running_total
    FROM sessions s
    JOIN transactions t
    ON s.session_id = t.session_id
    WHERE s.session_ts >= '2020-01-01' AND s.session_ts < '2020-02-01'
  ) sub
Where running_total = 0
AND row_num >= 2
```

Result from a sample table:

[image: Final Table]

Open to any feedback, thanks in advance. Not sure if the above query is the correct answer.  Also wondering if I could also show individual session_id per visitor_id like so:

[image: Example Table]

Comment: If no transaction is part of the requirement then an inner join can't work.

Comment: If "no transaction" meant $0 and still records a session_id would an inner join work then? Also, would my query work to identify "no transaction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume a session is a visit.  So that would be:

```
select s.visitor_id
from sessions s
where s.session_ts >= '2020-01-01' and s.session_ts < '2020-02-01' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from transactions t
                  where t.session_id = s.session_id
                 )
group by s.visitor_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: Great suggestion and works perfectly. If I had to assume that "no transaction" meant $0 and still recorded a session_id, would my query work?

Comment: @KevinKung . . . I don't understand what your comment means.  You can adjust the `not exists` logic to compare transactions of a particular type, such as those with an amount greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no negative transactions it would sort of work except that you didn't put an `order by` in the "running total," so you'd need to fix that. While you called it a running total in the alias but it's not really running at all. Not sure if that was confusion about naming or implementation. Yours would be on the right track if you sorted by dollars in reverse order so that non-zero rows appear first so that when you've gotten to the second row and running total is still zero then this visitor must indeed qualify. But that's a bit roundabout.

To get visitors alone it would also make more sense to me to just use a plain `group by` to do the job. This would have been my recommedation:

```
GROUP BY s.visitor_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 AND SUM(revenue) = 0
```

But since you want to retain session ids you do want analytic functions after all:

```
SELECT visitor_id, session_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY visitor_id ORDER BY session_ts) as row_num
FROM 
(
    SELECT s.visitor_id, s.session_id, s.sessions_ts, 
        SUM(revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY s.visitor_id) as total,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.visitor_id) as num_sessions
    FROM sessions s INNER JOIN transactions t
        ON s.session_id = t.session_id
    WHERE s.session_ts >= '2020-01-01' AND s.session_ts < '2020-02-01'
) sub
WHERE total = 0 AND total_sessions >= 2
```

There's no clear purpose in including the zero-dollar columns as output which is why I left them out. You may not even need that row number column though notice it's in the outer query now.

If negative revenue is possible then a sum won't always work. Consider comparing these two values for equality instead:

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.visitor_id)
```

and

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN revenue = 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY s.visitor_id)
```